# Can't boot from a USB stick to install Windows 7 Pro on Asus K55N

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-installation, asus-laptop, filesystem-corruption

I have been at this since the 19th when all I wanted to do was downgrade from Win 7 Ultimate to Win 7 Pro.

I hired someone who said his software could do it and it couldn't.

Then he wanted to reformat which would have been my 2nd time in 2-3 days since I just had someone put in a new SSD HD in this old laptop.

Well we couldn't install windows. Nothing would work, so he told me to format & I did, but I got no response saying it worked.

This allowed Windows to be installed, but then the nightmare continued where even when I installed the drivers, my screen was HUGE as if there were no graphic drivers & I couldn't install several pieces of software.

It turns out there were NO  Windows updates on this version (no .NET) so it took hours to update & finally I was able to install all software & see all graphics, but then I started to notice problems with Evernote. Problems I've never had since 2014.

I also started to hear audio issues (intermittent crackles in my headset), then grinding noises from the HD & a ding of a USB or headset being inserted when I wasn't doing anything.

I hired someone else because I knew something was seriously wrong. He said it sounds like Windows is missing some files & could fix the issues so I don't have to reinstall. Of course he never did, he just played around scanning my HDs & of course nothing was wrong.

When he said we would have to install Windows, nothing would work. It turns out the USB stick wasn't being recognized on that right USB port.

Then I called my website coder. We went through everything. Two different sticks, all 3 ports, I changed the bios boot order & this time I could see the sticks, but I still couldn't get to the Windows install screen.

Over the last 2 days, either I get the light blue screen that tells me there's something wrong with the computer & tries to repair it & then it fails and tries to do a check scan (I think it's called) or it just goes to the Windows screen.

Or it goes to the page with which country you are in & when I tried to go to the drive there, nothing worked either.

This Windows is now totally corrupted & I'm surprised I'm able to log in at all. I've gotten lots of warnings & errors & even my Thunderbird isn't working well.

Please help. I can't lose my computer.

Thanks a ton

Comment: 1. You paid money for this service, get it done correctly. Seek legal advice. 2. Windows 7 is deprecated. If you cannot update to Windows 10 or 11, try another OS such as Linux. Ubuntu can be installed from USB is less than 20 minutes, with minimal user knowledge or interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the great computer store who did EVERYTHING in like 20 minutes said & he actually got it to the Windows install screen within 2 LOL...

"modified installer that boots through a linux loader which seem to be incompatible with this laptop BIOS, so you have to go into Bios and then save and exit, and then boot override"

I hope that helps someone else so they don't have to be stressed and waste over a week of dealing with incompetence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).